# how to require "activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb" in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use the functions ".hour", ".minute",etc. in my rails model.
These are coming from following library: activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb.

**What is the best way to access this in my model?** The code is working in the rails console so I assume the file is available.

I tried doing the following in the top of my model (like mentioned in the documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html):

```
require 'activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb'
```

and got this error:

```
cannot load such file -- activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb
```

It feels like such a noobish question but I can't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#how-to-load-core-extensions) recommends to use the following pattern (in combination with [the specific date extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date-calculations)):

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/date/calculations'
```

Comment: thanks, looks like I was looking at the wrong thing.